# как сменить стиль стандартной кнопки на свою

Tags: android

после обновления по не понимаю как сменить стиль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: после какого обновления? приложите код текстом, у вас градиент, который возможно не правильно работает на кнопке

Comment: тут в тексте стиля все правильно,делал и свой авторский,и брал с ютуба,итог никакой не видно,видно если в меню дизайна ставлю light no action bar,если поменять в манифесте,при запуске ошибка